# What is the effect of "The Ground Effect" on a load bearing structure?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, differential-geometry, aerodynamics

[image] If a train was made to utilize the ground effect, (or plane made to follow a rail) not to have any contact with the ground other than air, would the rail need to be so heavily built since the air is distributing the weight?

Keep in mind the fastest train's full weight is still supported by a rail suspended with magnets. Also, I understand the dynamics of ground effect and I wonder if utilizing ground effect in this could increase the speed of the train while retaining some efficiency. In this scenario, the train would be suspended over a rail by air not magnets; possibly bracketed by magnets to keep it fixed to a platform or rail. A plane could work, but the idea is the vehicle is still fixed to the (possibly an existing) rail but not supporting by it.

Another way to ask, is how much would a very large cruise missile shaped vehicle benefit from using ground effect (possibly using curved surface area to follow the contour of the vehicle) verses not? How sturdy would that rail need to be?

Comment: I found a video on this train in the picture. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=029XfV6vHyA  Today this experimental concept I propose, would be most efficiently be propelled by magnets using electricity instead of a turbine engine. But a turbine engine and lighter missile shaped train would be easier to manufacture to prove my conceptual vehicle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ground effect, the moving vehicle is going so fast and is so close to the ground that it is riding on a bubble of air that is trapped between the vehicle and the ground. The ground is still supporting its weight, through the action of the compressed air in between the vehicle and the ground.

It takes less work to move a vehicle through the air when it is flying in ground effect, and there are vehicles which have been designed to take advantage of this. But the smaller a vehicle (like for example an airplane) is, the closer it needs to get to the ground to enter ground effect (the rule of thumb is one wingspan or less), and for a cruise missile it would fly into the trees before it could get close enough.

Since cruise missiles are subsonic and leave a big thermal exhaust plume, they would also be easily shot down if they were trying to cash in on ground effect while on their way to blow up their target.

Comment: Your answer did point out some flaws in my question.

Comment: The ground effect on an aircraft flying close to the ground doesn't depend on the compressibility of air. It would work the same for a vehicle in water close to the bottom.

Comment: If you can enlarge upon that, I'll edit my answer to reflect it- Or if you want to post an answer of your own I'll delete mine. -NN